# iOS - Custom animations in switching view controllers programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uistoryboard

I'm trying to switch view controllers in swift programmatically with animation:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())

var appDelegateTemp : AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
var view : UIView? = appDelegateTemp.window!.rootViewController?.view
destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as? UIViewController

UIView.transitionFromView(view!, toView: destinationViewController!.view, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromBottom,
        completion: { (completed : Bool) -> Void in
        var application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        var appDelegateTemp : AppDelegate = application.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegateTemp.window!.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController
    }
)
```

I set animation options to "TransitionFlipFromBottom", cause I couldn't find some fade out animation

So is there a way to use custom animations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can animate the transition however you would like using custom `UIView` animations. For example, a basic slide transition where the new view slides in from the left and the old view slides out to the right:

```
CGSize screenSize = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size;

CGRect toViewStartFrame = toView.frame;
CGRect toViewEndFrame = fromView.frame;
CGRect fromViewEndFrame = fromView.frame;

toViewStartFrame.origin.x = -screenSize.width;
fromViewEndFrame.origin.x = screenSize.width;

[fromView.superview addSubview:toView];
toView.frame = toViewStartFrame;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 usingSpringWithDamping:0.5 initialSpringVelocity:0.5 options:0 animations:^{
    toView.frame = toViewEndFrame;
    fromView.frame = fromViewEndFrame;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [fromView removeFromSuperview];
    fromView = nil;
}];
```

The basic premise is to set the `toView`'s end frame and the `fromView`'s end frame, then use `UIView` animations. Just make sure to remove the `fromView` from the superview and `nil` it out afterward, or you may create a memory leak. The way you transition in example code handles this step for you.